# looping a sequence of numbers

Tags: r, seq

I need to generate the following sequence of numbers:

```
from 101 to 124 then
from 201 to 224
```

and so on. I need to repeat this pattern 7 times, up to 724.

I know I can simply use

```
c(101:124,201:224, ...)
```

but I suspect there is an easier way. Maybe a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `seq` with `sapply`

```
c(sapply(seq(101, 700, by = 100), function(i) i:(i+23)))
```

Or we can use `rep`

```
(101:124) +rep(0:6, each = 24)*100
#[1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118
#[19] 119 120 121 122 123 124 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212
#[37] 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 301 302 303 304 305 306
#[55] 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324
#[73] 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418
#[91] 419 420 421 422 423 424 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512
#[109] 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 601 602 603 604 605 606
#[127] 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624
#[145] 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718
#[163] 719 720 721 722 723 724
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

We can use either the `outer` or `CJ`(cross join), both of which list all the combinations of elements from the two vector arguments. By specifying the reduce function as "+", where for `outer`, there is a parameter placeholder while for `CJ` you will have to explicitly use the `Reduce` function, they should produce the results as wanted. Just to be noted, the `outer` function will result in a matrix, so we use `as.vector` to convert it to a 1d array.

```
as.vector(outer(1:24, (1:7)*100, "+"))
```

or

```
Reduce("+", data.table::CJ(1:24, (1:7)*100))
```

Comment: Thanks, it does its job!

Comment: @lmo Thanks for notifying me. I will add some text for explanation.

Comment: Sure thing. I think your answers add to the post. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Using common 'for' loop:

```
> vect=c(); for(i in seq(from=101,to=701, by=100)) vect = c(vect, seq(from=i,to=i+23))
> vect
  [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 201 202 203 204 205 206 207
 [32] 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314
 [63] 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421
 [94] 422 423 424 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 601 602 603 604
[125] 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711
[156] 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724
```